# How to get an array as an input for a GraphQL resolver

Tags: typescript, rest, graphql, nestjs, graphql-js

I want to get an array of strings as `ids` parameter from the query variables and use it inside my resolver. Below here is my code.

#### People.resolver.ts

```js
import {
  Resolver, Query, Mutation, Args,
} from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { People } from './People.entity';
import { PeopleService } from './People.service';

@Resolver(() => People)
export class PeopleResolver {
  constructor(private readonly peopleService: PeopleService) { }

  @Mutation(() => String)
  async deletePeople(@Args('ids') ids: string[]) : Promise<String> {
    const result = await this.peopleService.deletePeople(ids);
    return JSON.stringify(result);
  }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error,

```bash
[Nest] 8247   - 06/22/2020, 6:32:53 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/run-migrations, POST} route +1ms
(node:8247) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: You need to provide explicit type for PeopleResolver#deletePeople parameter #0 !
    at Object.findType (/Users/eranga/Documents/Project/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/helpers/findType.js:17:15)
    at Object.getParamInfo (/Users/eranga/Documents/Project/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/helpers/params.js:9:49)
    at /Users/eranga/Documents/Project/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/decorators/Arg.js:9:159
    at /Users/eranga/Documents/Project/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/decorators/args.decorator.js:34:113
    at /Users/eranga/Documents/Project/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/storages/lazy-metadata.storage.js:11:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at LazyMetadataStorageHost.load (/Users/eranga/Documents/Project/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/storages/lazy-metadata.storage.js:11:22)
    at GraphQLSchemaBuilder.<anonymous> (/Users/eranga/Documents/Project/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql-schema-builder.js:31:57)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/eranga/Documents/Project/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql-schema-builder.js:17:71
(node:8247) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:8247) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

---

I also tried the following variations,

```js
@Args('ids', () => string[]) ids: string[]

@Args('ids', () => String[]) ids: String[]

@Args('ids', () => [String]) ids: String[]

@Args('ids', { type: () => String[] }) ids: String[]
```

---

But if I am to change my mutation like below to take a single string it works.

```js
@Mutation(() => String)
async deletePeople(@Args('id') id: string) : Promise<String> {
  const result = await this.peopleService.deletePeople([id]);
  return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This works when the input type argument is defined as,

```js
@Args({ name: 'ids', type: () => [String] }) ids: String[]
```

Below is how the mutation resolver looks like:

```js
@UseGuards(GraphqlAuthGuard)
@Mutation(() => String)
async deletePeople(@Args({ name: 'ids', type: () => [String] }) ids: String[]) : Promise<String> {
  const result = await this.peopleService.deletePeople(ids);
  return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

Credits go to @vinujan.s

Comment: I am trieng to achieve simular with an array of objects. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You should change your resolver to get the argument like
```@Args({ name: <NAME_OF_YOUR_OBJECT_VARIABLE>, type: () => [<YOUR_OBJECT_INPUT_TYPE_AS_A_GRAPHQL_TYPE] }```

Comment: how can we pass multiple arguments? let's say we have updated mutations. i need to pass id and payload separatley. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can create 2 arg parameters. `deletePeople(@Args({ name: 'ids', type: () => [String] }) ids: String[], @Args({ name: 'payload', type: () => PayloadInputType }) payload: PayloadInputType)`

Comment: Is this outdated? it seems it answers no overload in this call

Comment: The answer is not outdated. I didn't understand what you meant by "it answers no overload in this call".

Comment: Yes, it is outdated, the new overload is like this - 
`@Args('<NAME_OF_YOUR_OBJECT_VARIABLE>', () => [<YOUR_OBJECT_INPUT_TYPE_AS_A_GRAPHQL_TYPE] `

So, our example here becomes - 
`async deletePeople(@Args('ids', () => [String]) ids: String[])`

Comment: I think the answer is still valid as of today. I can see that the latest version ([v10.0.16](https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/blob/bf1ffcc3d920b2da50868d924c2b03fc697811b1/packages/graphql/lib/decorators/args.decorator.ts#L62)) still contains the overload matching the answer. However, I don't see an overload matching your answer though.